# Convert a column in a dask dataframe to a TaggedDocument for Doc2Vec

Tags: python, dask, gensim, doc2vec

## Intro

Currently I am trying to use dask in concert with gensim to do NLP document computation and I'm running into an issue when converting my corpus into a "[TaggedDocument](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html#gensim.models.doc2vec.TaggedDocument)".

Because I've tried so many different ways to wrangle this problem I'll list my attempts.

Each attempt at dealing with this problem is met with slightly different woes.

## First some initial givens.

### The Data

```
df.info()
<class 'dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame'>
Columns: 5 entries, claim_no to litigation
dtypes: object(2), int64(3)
```

```
  claim_no   claim_txt I                                    CL ICC lit
0 8697278-17 battery comprising interior battery active ele... 106 2 0
```

### Desired Output

```
>>tagged_document[0]
>>TaggedDocument(words=['battery', 'comprising', 'interior', 'battery', 'active', 'elements', 'battery', 'cell', 'casing', 'said', 'cell', 'casing', 'comprising', 'first', 'casing', 'element', 'first', 'contact', 'surface', 'second', 'casing', 'element', 'second', 'contact', 'surface', 'wherein', 'assembled', 'position', 'first', 'second', 'contact', 'surfaces', 'contact', 'first', 'second', 'casing', 'elements', 'encase', 'active', 'materials', 'battery', 'cell', 'interior', 'space', 'wherein', 'least', 'one', 'gas', 'tight', 'seal', 'layer', 'arranged', 'first', 'second', 'contact', 'surfaces', 'seal', 'interior', 'space', 'characterized', 'one', 'first', 'second', 'contact', 'surfaces', 'comprises', 'electrically', 'insulating', 'void', 'volume', 'layer', 'first', 'second', 'contact', 'surfaces', 'comprises', 'formable', 'material', 'layer', 'fills', 'voids', 'surface', 'void', 'volume', 'layer', 'hermetically', 'assembled', 'position', 'form', 'seal', 'layer'], tags=['8697278-17'])
>>len(tagged_document) == len(df['claim_txt'])
```

## Error Number 1 No Generators Allowed

```
def read_corpus_tag_sub(df,corp='claim_txt',tags=['claim_no']):
    for i, line in enumerate(df[corp]):
        yield gensim.models.doc2vec.TaggedDocument(gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(line), (list(df.loc[i,tags].values)))

tagged_document = df.map_partitions(read_corpus_tag_sub,meta=TaggedDocument)
tagged_document = tagged_document.compute()
```

TypeError: Could not serialize object of type generator.

I found no way of getting around this while still using a generator. A fix for this would be great! As this works perfectly fine for regular pandas.

## Error Number 2 Only the first element of each partition

```
def read_corpus_tag_sub(df,corp='claim_txt',tags=['claim_no']):
    for i, line in enumerate(df[corp]):
        return gensim.models.doc2vec.TaggedDocument(gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(line), (list(df.loc[i,tags].values)))

tagged_document = df.map_partitions(read_corpus_tag_sub,meta=TaggedDocument)
tagged_document = tagged_document.compute()
```

This one is a bit dumb as the function won't iterate (I know) but gives the desired format, but only returns the first row in each partition.

## Error Number 3 function call hangs with 100% cpu

```
def read_corpus_tag_sub(df,corp='claim_txt',tags=['claim_no']):
    tagged_list = []
    for i, line in enumerate(df[corp]):
        tagged = gensim.models.doc2vec.TaggedDocument(gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(line), (list(df.loc[i,tags].values)))
        tagged_list.append(tagged)
    return tagged_list
```

Near as I can tell when refactoring the return outside the loop this function hangs builds memory in the dask client and my CPU utilization goes to 100% but no tasks are being computed. Keep in mind I'm calling the function the same way.

## Pandas Solution

```
def tag_corp(corp,tag):
    return gensim.models.doc2vec.TaggedDocument(gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(corp), ([tag]))

tagged_document = [tag_corp(x,y) for x,y in list(zip(df_smple['claim_txt'],df_smple['claim_no']))]
```

List comp I haven't time tested this solution

## Other Pandas Solution

```
tagged_document = list(read_corpus_tag_sub(df))
```

This solution will chug along pretty much for hours. However I don't have enough memory to juggle this thing when it's done.

## Conclusion(?)

I feel Super lost right now. Here is a list of threads I've looked at. I admit to being really new to dask I've just spent so much time and I feel like I'm on a fools errand.

1. [Dask Bag from generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50862165/creating-a-dask-bag-from-a-generator)
2. [Processing Text With Dask](https://medium.com/mindorks/speeding-up-text-pre-processing-using-dask-45cc3ede1366)
3. [Speed up Pandas apply using Dask](https://gdcoder.com/speed-up-pandas-apply-function-using-dask-or-swifter-tutorial/)
4. [How do you parallelize apply() on Pandas Dataframes making use of all cores on one machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45545110/how-do-you-parallelize-apply-on-pandas-dataframes-making-use-of-all-cores-on-o)
5. [python dask DataFrame, support for (trivially parallelizable) row apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31361721/python-dask-dataframe-support-for-trivially-parallelizable-row-apply)
6. [What is map_partitions doing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39215617/what-is-map-partitions-doing)
7. [simple dask map_partitions example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47125665/simple-dask-map-partitions-example)
8. [The Docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.map_partitions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the Dask APIs/limitations, but generally:

- if you can iterate over your data as (words, tags) tuples – even ignoring the `Doc2Vec`/`TaggedDocument` steps – then the Dask side will have been handled, and converting those tuples to `TaggedDocument` instances should be trivial
- in general for large datasets, you don't want to (and may not have enough RAM to) instantiate the full dataset as a `list` in memory – so your attempts that involve a `list()` or `.append()` may be working, up to a point, but exhausting local memory (causing severe swapping) and/or just not reaching the end of your data.

The preferable approach to large datasets is to create an iterable object that, every time it is asked to iterate over the data (because `Doc2Vec` training will require multiple passes), can offer up each and every item in turn – but never reading the entire dataset into an in-memory object.

A good blogpost on this pattern is: [Data streaming in Python: generators, iterators, iterables](https://rare-technologies.com/data-streaming-in-python-generators-iterators-iterables/)

Given the code you've shown, I suspect the right approach for you may be like:

```
from gensim.utils import simple_preprocess

class MyDataframeCorpus(object):
    def __init__(self, source_df, text_col, tag_col):
        self.source_df = source_df
        self.text_col = text_col
        self.tag_col = tag_col

    def __iter__(self):
        for i, row in self.source_df.iterrows():
            yield TaggedDocument(words=simple_preprocess(row[self.text_col]), 
                                 tags=[row[self.tag_col]])

corpus_for_doc2vec = MyDataframeCorpus(df, 'claim_txt', 'claim_no')
```

Comment: I will read that post and thank you very much!

Currently I've janked my way around this problem by building the entire tagged corpus in memory, then picking every million items or so. Then clearing the items from the list.

Then building the model vocab a million rows at a time deleting each list from memory as soon as it's done building.

My next plan was to then reload each tagged list into memory train the model and then update the model with each subset of a million rows.

Comment: So building on the code you have shown me above. Can I then just do something like model.build_vocab(corpus_for_doc2vec) ?

I apologize if this is ignorant I've really only been coding python for less than year or so.

Comment: You definitely *don't* want to be doing your own batching & calling `build_vocab()` or `train()` multiple times – especially when a streaming iterable can give `Doc2Vec` what it expects, with much less fuss. Once you have `corpus_for_doc2vec`, which is able to repeatedly iterate over all your docs as `TaggedDocument` instances, then yes: you can do `d2v_model.buld_vocab(corpus_for_doc2vec)` and then `d2v_model.train(corpus_for_doc2vec, ...)`.

Comment: Thank you so much man. When I get home I'm going to try this out. I am really grateful for the help. I have seen your name in literally every gensim doc2vec related post. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I just can't believe it's actually this easy ... Doing it this way took 31 minutes to build a vocabulary of 860 million words with 8.2 million examples. and took 40 minutes to train. This is incredible I'd take you out to lunch if I could thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it's working! That's a bit faster training than I would have expected with 8+ million texts – 10-20 epochs is most common in published results. (You may want to enable logging at the INFO level & watch the output for hints whether vocabulary-handling & training-cycles are all happening as desired, or differently.)

Comment: You were correct. `WARNING : train() called with an empty iterator (if not intended, be sure to provide a corpus that offers restartable iteration = an iterable).` followed by `INFO : EPOCH - 2 : training on 0 raw words (0 effective words) took 0.0s, 0 effective words/s
2019-06-21 02:05:59,138 : WARNING : EPOCH - 2 : supplied example count (0) did not equal expected count (8216031)`

The same error appears for EPOCH 50 (i'll reduce this) . My guess is this is solved similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34166369/generator-is-not-an-iterator  .

Comment: Hmm, the `corpus_for_doc2vec` instance of `MyDataframeCorpus` **should** be an iterable sequence properly capable of repeated iterations - though it is a common error to pass just a single iterator, which gets consumed by the vocab-discovery pass. A quickie test of whether a corpus is multiple-iterable is to run `iter(corpus).next()` twice in a row, to ensure it returns the 1st item twice. (A slower test that actually requests every item is to run `sum(1 for _ in corpus)` twice in a row, to ensure it reports the full expected count of items both times.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195367/discussion-between-zdwhite-and-gojomo).

Comment: As far as I can tell, SO chat hides info that could be useful to future askers/searchers, so I prefer not to use it.

Comment: I'll post an edit to my question and update it with the useful information

Answer (score 1):

Right, so you're close with this code

```
def read_corpus_tag_sub(df,corp='claim_txt',tags=['claim_no']):
    for i, line in enumerate(df[corp]):
        yield gensim.models.doc2vec.TaggedDocument(gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(line), (list(df.loc[i,tags].values)))

tagged_document = df.map_partitions(read_corpus_tag_sub,meta=TaggedDocument)
```

But as you saw producing a generator isn't very helpful for Dask.  Instead, you could have your function return a series

```
def myfunc(df, *args, **kwargs):
    output = []
    for i, line in enumerate(df["my_series"])
        result = ...
        output.append([])
    return pd.Series(output)
```

Or, you could probably just use the `df.apply` method, which takes a function that converts a single row into a single row.

You might also want to switch to [Dask Bag](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/bag.html), which does handle things like lists and generators more naturally than Pandas/Dask DataFrame.

Comment: So I applied what gojomo gave me below to my problem and it worked very elegantly. Which shifted my use for dask. In the sense that the below code works when I'm holding my corpus (pandas df) in memory. So if I could get that to work in concert with a dask dataframe I feel like I would have been given the keys to a ferrari.