# Efficient use of multiple cores with dask distributed and gensim

Tags: python, multithreading, dask, gensim, dask-distributed

I have a huge data frame that doesn't fit into memory. Thus I access it in Python via `dask` (distributed).

I want to train a Word2Vec/Doc2Vec model with the package `gensim` based on the entries of one column in the data frame, that's why I built an iterator like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56681210/convert-a-column-in-a-dask-dataframe-to-a-taggeddocument-for-doc2vec).

Now, `gensim` trains using multiple cores whose number I need to specify, and similarly `dask` allows me to use multiple cores, too. So far I gave all available cores to `dask` and the same number of cores to `gensim`. My reasoning would be that fetching data and training on the data are exclusive tasks that cannot be done at the same time, so `gensim` and `dask` shouldn't fight over the cores.

Indeed, there are no error messages, but still, training seems to be quite slow, and I suspect there's a better way to distribute the work. Does anyone have experience in this matter?

Comment: Because there's no facility in gensim for integrating with `dask`, or more generally recombining models that were trained in a separate, distributed fashion, I would try to eliminate both `dask` and dataframes as factors to consider from the `gensim` step. Get just the data you need for the `gensim` step in a streamable, pre-tokenized file (however large), then stream that to Word2Vec/Doc2Vec on a single many-core machine.

Answer (score 0):

Combining two libraries that both try to use multi-threaded parallelism can be counter-productive.  Having too many threads active can cause contention and slow things down.  I recommend setting one of the two libraries to use only a single thread.

For Dask, you can do this with the following:

```
dask.config.set(scheduler="single-threaded")
```

https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/scheduling.html